# Running python demo script with dll/pyd dependencies

Tags: python, c++, dll

I'm writing some python code that depends on a c++ library (I'm using Boost.Python). I use cmake to build and put the library dll and pyd files into bin. My folder structure looks a bit like this:

```
Project
|-- bin: folder where test executables, dll, and pyd files get put after build
|-- cpp: all cpp/h files to build the dll
|-- python: the cpp files with the boost.python interface as well as python code that depends on it (and the dlls)
|-- test: cpp code with tests
```

To run my python files, I need the dll and pyd files in the same directory as the python script. Currently, I have cmake copy the .py files in python into bin for me to run and test. However, I really don't like this as it is ugly adn cumbersome. I read that I could add my bin folder to the PYTHONPATH and PATH variables to solve this, but this would make my python code a little ugly I think.

I am a novice at Python; therefore, I was wondering if there are better ways to handle this issue. Ideally, I'd like to run my python scripts/module from the python folder so I can debug from an environment like PyCharm or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I'm settling for adding the bin folder to the python path programmatically with

```
import os, sys
moduleDir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()) + os.sep + "bin"
sys.path.insert(0, moduleDir)
```

It solves my issue in the short term although it doesn't look nice.